# Changing a string of blanks to a string of 0s in a specific column range in a data file

Tags: text-processing, awk

We're using Redhat Linux 7.9 with `bsh`.

I want to go through a data file and replace all the fields between columns 10 and 20 that have blanks with 0s.

So if I have an example file of:

```
#######################

#######################

#######################

#########        ######

#######################

#######################

#######################

#######################
```

I want the script to make it look like :

```
#######################

#######################

#######################

#########000000000#####

#######################

#######################

#######################

#######################
```

I've tried using the following:

```
awk '{val=substr($0,10,9);gsub(val,"     ","000000000")}1' scr1
```

But it only returns the original file. What did I miss?

Comment: Is this very different to what `tr ' ' '0' <file` would do?

Comment: @Kusalananda I think it's just a bad choice of example and there's other blanks in  the input that the OP hasn't shown us.

Comment: does your input file really have empty lines between each line, or is that just because you don't know how to format plain text on this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the `gsub()` argument order and meaning wrong, see the man page.

It seems like this might be what you're trying to do, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '{val=substr($0,10,9)} gsub(/ /,0,val){$0=substr($0,1,9) val substr($0,19)} 1' file
#######################

#######################

#######################

#########00000000######

#######################

#######################

#######################

#######################
```

Answer (score 4):

Perl can make short work of this as shown.

Since perl indexes begin with a zero, so the 10th column is 9 and col10...20 have 20-10+1=11 elements in them.

```
$ perl -lpe 'substr($_, 9, 11) =~ tr/ /0/' file
```

Outputs:-

```
#######################

#######################

#######################
12345678901234567890
#########00000000000###
         12345678901
#######################

#######################
```